# Generate service from wsdl

Tags: java, jaxb, wsdl, client

how can I generate service from .wsdl file? I'm trying to do it with this command:
wsdl2java - client example.wsdl
But I'm getting 'wsdl2java' is not recognized as an internal or external command. How can I install it?

Comment: I think this is the wrong approach. Too wizard-y; too Microsoft.  A better approach is "contract first", like Spring web services.  Start with a schema for your request and response and generate the WSDL from that.

Comment: I got .wsdl file from host, I have to write client for it.

Comment: Host meaning an IBM mainframe?  That's a shame.  What did Google say when you searched for that tool?

Comment: Host - another organisations server, they have server and I have to do client for it.

Comment: Ask them for their schema: http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

Use following command:

```
wsimport -keep wsdlFileName
```

It will generate all necessary files for wsdl client. wsimport is native tool for java and if you have java you do not need install anything.